# Где находится каталог с письмами в modx revo?

Tags: modx

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где в modx revo находится каталог, в который попадают отправленные при помощи `formit` сообщения при не настроенном почтовом сервисе.

Answer (score 2):

А с чего вы взяли, что там есть такой каталог? FormIt использует php-класс, отправляющий письмо на указанный в tpl адрес. Если адрес указан неверно, то за его доставку отвечает уже не снипет, а почтовый сервер. Yandex.почта для домена, например, автоматически сливает все письма, пришедшие на несуществующие адреса, на один ящик.